# Autowire an interface having multiple implementations, each having multiple parameterized constructors?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot, and I need to dynamically initialise interface implementations based on some condition. Each implementation has multiple parameterized constructors, and their parameter values are also obtained at runtime. The implementation to be initialised and the constructor to be called is all decided at runtime. Perhaps the below code will make my problem clearer. I have an interface:

```java
public Interface MyInterface {
}
```

I have 2 implementations of this interface:

```java
@Component
public class MyImpl1 implements MyInterface {
    
    @Autowired
    AutowiredObject1 autowiredObject1;
    
    public MyImpl1(Long arg1) {
        autowiredObject1.someMethod();
    }
    
    public MyImpl1(Long arg1, String arg2) {
        autowiredObject1.someMethod();
    }
```

And

```java
@Component
public class MyImpl2 implements MyInterface {
    
    @Autowired
    AutowiredObject2 autowiredObject2;
    
    public MyImpl2(Long arg1) {
        autowiredObject2.someMethod();
    }
    
    public MyImpl2(Long arg1, String arg2) {
        autowiredObject2.someMethod();
    }
```

Now I have a helper class, wherein I want to autowire MyInterface. The problem is, the object of MyInterface needs to be initialised dynamically based on some conditions. The constructor to be called is also decided dynamically, as follows:

```java
@Service
public  MyHelperClass {
    
    @Autowired
    MyInterface myInterface;
    
    public myInterface getMyInterfaceObject (Long arg1, String arg2) {
        if ( //condition 1) {
           myInterface = new MyImpl1(arg1);
        }
        
        else if ( //condition 2) {
           myInterface = new MyImpl1(arg1, arg2);
        }
        
        else if ( //condition 3) {
           myInterface = new MyImpl2(arg1);
        }
        
        else if ( //condition 4) {
           myInterface = new MyImpl2(arg1, arg2);
        }
        
        return myInterface;
    }
```

Obviously, the above code doesn't work and I get

> HikariPool-1-Shutdown initiated
>
> HikariPool-1-Shutdown completed

on the console when I run the application.

However, when I:

- remove the @Component annotation from MyImpl1 and MyImpl2,
- remove the Autowired myInterface object from MyHelperClass,
- remove the autowiredObjects from MyImpl1 and MyImpl2,
- autowire the autowiredObjects in MyHelperClass and then pass them to the constructor of MyImpl1 and MyImpl2, the application works fine.

I cannot follow the second approach, though, because down the line I need to autowire more beans in the implementation classes and I cannot keep on having them obtained through the constructor.

Is there any way possible to autowire MyInterface in the first place in MyHelperClass, and dynamically initialise its object based on the condition? I tried creating a Configuration class but I kept getting a null pointer exception on

```
autowiredObject1.someMethod();
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: in MyHelperClass  instead  of using new you should be using  Condiotnal annotation to get the beans 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear as to which conditions you would create those beans.  Perhaps @Conditional will help.  You can find various bean initialization ways provided by Spring [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/package-summary.html).  Specially look for annotations in this package like on satisfying certain expression you can use @ConditionalOnExpression

You can also define your own custom condition for bean creation if you implement Condition interface.

Here is a nice [article](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-conditionals/#:%7E:text=Spring%20has%20introduced%20the%20%40Conditional,have%20to%20implement%20them%20ourselves.) I found which might be of some use

From helper class/factory it appears you would want all those classes ready/created as @Component creates singleton. If you are looking to create new instances every time perhaps you should use Prototype.

Comment: I tried injecting the beans through a Configuration class keeping the scope as Prototype but I got a null pointer exception for the Autowired object.

Comment: You may need to evaluate how your classes/objects are related and constructed.  Often NPE means it is not getting all the beans required to construct it, or you have some assumptions during construction which are not fullfilled.

Answer (score 0):

Use **@Qualifier** annotation is used to differentiate beans of the same interface
Take look at Spring Boot documentation:https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers

```
@Service
@@Qualifier("first")
public class MyImpl1 implements MyInterface {
    
    @Autowired
    AutowiredObject1 autowiredObject1;
    
    public MyImpl1(Long arg1) {
        autowiredObject1.someMethod();
    }
    
    public MyImpl1(Long arg1, String arg2) {
        autowiredObject1.someMethod();
    }




@Service
@Qualifier("secondService")
public class MyImpl2 implements MyInterface {
    
    @Autowired
    AutowiredObject2 autowiredObject2;
    
    public MyImpl2(Long arg1) {
        autowiredObject2.someMethod();
    }
    
    public MyImpl2(Long arg1, String arg2) {
        autowiredObject2.someMethod();
    }
```

Comment: How can I supply values to the constructors of first and secondService at runtime?